# Which WPF controls support data binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

Is there a list somewhere? I spent a lot of time yesterday trying to bind *an ObservableCollection<string>* to a RichTextBox, then when that didn't work to a FlowDocument (which I eventually found a simple work-around for). If there isn't a list is there some intellisense trick to find out? I found it really strange that FlowDocument didn't support data binding *to a collection*. It has a DataContext property that shows up in Intellisense so I figured there was some way to bind a collection. That coupled with the fact that  supports *single item* binding made me certain I just couldn't find the proper property. Does everyone just eventually figure this out the hard way or did I miss something obvious?

[Edit - and the italicized text above are edits]
I guess I'm such a beginner I don't even know how to ask the question properly. I have half my answer. What I really want to know, I now realize is two things.

1. how do I tell which controls can be bound to a collection (the answer from below is any control that has an ItemsSource property)
2. When looking at a control how do I know which of the properties are dependency properties that I can bind data to?  (I do realize - just now - that when I go to browser and look at each property the summary section is mentioning which properties are dependency properties. A little laborious to click on every property in a control but I can live with that if that's the easiest way to find out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that is derived from FrameworkElement (which is every WPF control to my knowledge) supports data binding.  However binding a collection requires a special type of binding.  You will need to bind to a ItemsControl or use a control that has the ItemsSource DependencyProperty

Comment: OK - This helps a lot. So I can type a <Control ....> and inside that type ItemsSource and if Intellisense doesn't show it then I can't bind a collection to that control. Now if I can just find an equally easy way to find out if a property is a dependency property.

Answer (score 2):

All WPF controls support DataBinding, on almost every property.  If you post specific examples, we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: My specific problem was yesterday's attempt to bind a collection to a RichTextBox and a FlowDocument. How does everyone know that those Don't support data binding? How do i keep from wasting time in the future on other controls that don't support it.

Comment: They do support DataBinding.  I'd suggest creating a new post with the exact details- what is it a collection of, what is the expected output, what code have you tried, what exceptions you have seen in the output window, etc.

Comment: @Tod: In Visual-Studio 2010 you can just type any property, press F1 and you will get to the documentation page (otherwise just go there manually). If there is a `Dependency Property Information` section it's a DP, e.g. [`TextBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) vs. [`ItemsControl.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items.aspx)

Comment: thanks for sticking with me. I actually had a [separate post on the specific problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339376/how-to-display-observablecollectionstring-in-a-usercontrol) I was having but I think I have it solved. I'm not good enough at this yet to ask proper questions. I was trying to bind an ObservableCollection<string> to a RTB or FlowDoc. Eventually found a work around (and if I could get paste to work I would be happy). Just trying to find out how to avoid problems in the future and I think I now see the light.

Answer (score 2):

[Data binding is supported on any `DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

> - The target property must be a dependency property. Most UIElement properties are dependency properties and most dependency properties, except read-only ones, support data binding by default. (Only DependencyObject types can define dependency properties and all UIElements derive from DependencyObject.)

In the case of a `RichTextbox` or `FlowDocument` you can achieve binding thru the [`Run.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.text.aspx) dependency property as of .Net 4.0. But keep in mind in a `RichTextBox`:

> Binding text to a `Run` object contained within `RichTextBox` is not supported. Editing operations within the `RichTextBox` may cause the binding to be cleared.

You can bind the `Document` property as well, however, this may require some additional logic if you need the textual data contained within.

Comment: XAML is only one way to declare bindings, it has no effect on whether you can do it or not. (removed that bit)

Comment: @H.B. thank you sir, it was a casualty of a rewritten sentence.

Comment: Thanks, this leads me to ask, how do I find out which properties are Dependency properties? I can hit F12 and go to the browser but I don't see any kind of special glyph or way to tell from the list of properties which ones are dependency properties.

Comment: @Tod: H.B. has an answer for you in another comment. I guess I don't understand what you're asking, because a cursory glance at the properties on the `RichTextBox` shows they all can be bound to, save the read-only ones. I think you're instead asking: how can I find out which controls can have their content bound *trivially*. In the case of an RTB, you bind through the `Document` property, which is non-trivial (hence, not useful for you).

Comment: Yeah I didn't ask this very well. I was trying to bind an ObservableCollection<string> to a RTB. (I'm also learning MVVM). It did seem to me that it should be trivial but I guess with RTB it's not. It was fairly trivial with a FlowDocument, but a little tricky. Even though I asked badly the answers here have helped a lot. Thanks to everyone.